# How to find a string in a file and then copy them to another file

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a text file which looks like this

```
*test_one 
123xyz
8y9asd
*test_ten
1232nkja
asd1233
*undo_six
asd876
*undo_nine
ase1n4
```

I wanted to split this file into two files which should like this.

File1

```
*test_one 
123xyz
8y9asd
*test_ten
1232nkja
```

File2

```
*undo_six
asd876
*undo_nine
ase1n4
```

The file size is too huge can run into GB's.

Since iterating line by line will be too memory intensive, I want to know can I use regex option to do this? if so can some one provide me a sample code how to use this?

Comment: iterating line by line is memory efficnet since you only ever hold one line in memory at a time so it wouldnt matter how large the file is. How are you deciding what should be in each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well its not exactly clear how you are deciding to split the data. Assuming that the lines which start with * are some sort of marker and that you want to group them by the prefix before the underscore you could use the below. It will create a new file with 1 number higher for every time it finds a new prefix, the file handle will be stored in a dict using the prefix as the key.

we can then write to the file based on the last prefix we seen.

```py
file_num = 0
file_prefix = ""
file_handles = {}

with open("test.txt") as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        if line.startswith("*"):
            prefix, _ = line.split("_")
            file_prefix = prefix
            if prefix not in file_handles:
                file_num += 1
                file_handles[prefix] = open(f"file{file_num}.txt", "w")
        if file_prefix:
            file_handles[file_prefix].write(line)

for file_handle in file_handles.values():
    file_handle.close()
```

Comment: I tried your code. it is giving Key Error' at Line#12

Comment: answering to your first question. Yes, I wanted to split the data based on * and the prefix before underscore.

Comment: Are all your lines which start with * in the same format? *someprefix_someother. Is the first line in your file a * prefix line?I.E you dont have any blank lines or header lines

Comment: Also if you make a sample file using the example data you provided in the questioin does the code at least work on the sample data?

Comment: The first line in my file is not with * . Those entries with *someprefix_someother are in some where middle lines (not the starting lines).

Comment: Ok that will be the issue. since there is no prefix seen there is no file open, yet it tries to write every line into a file. so what should happen with the first lines of the file? should they be split into any file or just ignored?

Comment: They should be ignored

Comment: I have updated the code with an if statment so it will only write a line when file prefix is set. So for the first lines before a prefix is seen they will essentially be skipped, they will be read but nothing done with them, only once we see a prefix and create a file will the lines following that prefix be writte into that prefix file